# Upgrade to version 4.0 causes browser to crash on cancel, retry or delete

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Have you had any reported issues with users upgrading to the latest version and experiencing this?

I have flipped our file list template to the new script tag template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="upload-list-template">
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
        <div class="btn">Upload a file</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
        <div>
            <div class="item">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale="true">
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
                <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

clicking any button results in a long running script browser crash.

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue with the live examples on fineuploader.com?  Which browser are you using?  Did you generate a custom build of fine uploader?  If not, how did you build Fine Uploader?  What messages are you seeing in the javascript console?  This information will be important to helping you out.

Comment: No reports of this so far and I'm not seeing issues in my test.  Your markup in your question is invalid due to a lack of a closing script tag as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. I  have the closing script tag and there is nothing in the console, the browser is frozen completely .. the browser is Chrome (latest version) .. I selected everything in the custom build, so no parts missing. Let me keep testing and I'll update you as I go

Comment: I ran some real-world tests on existing web applications as I updated them to version 4.0, and didn't run into any issues.  I recently discovered [this issue](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1021), which I plan to fix, but it's unrelated to what you are reporting.  Are you able to reproduce using any of the examples on fineuploader.com?

Comment: Hi. I am not able to repro it with examples, but it occurs if the widget is in a 'Retrying' state and you attempt to cancel. You have to Force Quit Chrome.

Comment: Ok, this is the specific information I was looking for.  Please [open up a bug report in the github repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new) so we can add it to the top of our list of things to investigate at the start of business tomorrow.  If this is reproducible, this is most definitely an edge case issue, but we will fix it if it is reproducible nonetheless.

Comment: I have a further update. In firefox, it says error is happening on line 5887 of fineuploader. It is a while loop:    while (currentNode.getAttribute(FILE_ID_ATTR) == null) {
                currentNode = el.parentNode;
            }

Comment: Thanks Craig.  For anyone else tracking this, the bug report is at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1023.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. By re-arranging the elements in the exact order of the example template.

Comment: The order doesn't matter, it's the number of levels below the file list container that trigger the bug, as far as the buttons are concerned.  I didn't down vote you but your answer is pretty sparse which probably compelled someone else to do so.  I will be contributing an answer once this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** This issue has been fixed in the just-released 4.0.1 hotfix version.

This was an issue that would only manifest itself when the items in the file portion of the template (such as the buttons) are two or more levels below the `.qq-file-list-selector` element.  By default, these items are only one level below this container, but in the modified template you posted in your question, they are 2 levels deep.

The fix to Fine Uploader's code is simple.  I changed:

```
while (currentNode.getAttribute(FILE_ID_ATTR) == null) {
    currentNode = el.parentNode;
}
```

to:

```
while (currentNode.getAttribute(FILE_ID_ATTR) == null) {
    currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
}
```